# How to evaluate these integrals?

Tags: integration

This is a problem of ordinary calculus. Given
\begin{align}
f(x)&=
    \left\{
        \begin{array}{ccc}
            k(0),&\quad 0\leq x<b\\
            k(x-b),& \quad b\leq x<b+a
        \end{array}
    \right.,\\
g(x)&=
    \left\{
        \begin{array}{cc}
            k(x),&\quad 0\leq x<a\\
            k(a),& \quad a\leq x<b+a
        \end{array}
    \right..
\end{align}
where $k(x)$ is a continuous function of $x\in[0,a]$ and $a,b>0$ $(a\neq b)$. If the values of $b$, $k(0)$, $k(a)$  $(k(a)\neq k(0)$ are fixed, do the following integrals separately have fixed values for arbitrary $a$ and $k(x)$ ($x\in(0,a)$)? How to prove it?

\begin{align}
I_{1}&=\int^{a+b}_{0}dx\int^{x}_{0}dy [f(x)-g(x)]\cos(x-y)[f(y)-g(y)],\\
I_{2}&=\int^{a+b}_{0}dx\int^{x}_{0}dy [f(x)-g(x)] \sin(x-y)[f(y)+g(y)].
\end{align}

This is true if $k(x)$ is a step function with the jump at any $x\in[0,a)$. For general case, I have tried to do translation for $g(x)$, however, still can not prove it.

Comment: This may be the wrong forum for this question.  And if you take it to math.se you should add your own attempts to solve it.

Comment: I don't think these integrals are fixed. Let $a=b=1$, $k(0)=0$, $k(1)=1$. For $k(x)=x$, Mathematica's NIntegrate command tells me that $I_1\approx 0.422644$. For $k(x)=x^7$, I get $I_1\approx 0.454156$.